# Having trouble taking derivative of a function and assigning it to a new function

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to take the derivative of a function and assign it to a different function name, but I am getting an error message (I think).

Here is my *Mathematica* input:

```
P[x_, t_] := ap Cos[2 Pi/lambda x - w t]
R[x_, t_] := Ro ap Cos[-2 Pi/lambda x - w t - 4 Pi L/lambda]

topr[x_, t_] := P[x, t] + R[x, t] + bo

botr[x_, t_] := P[x, t] + bi
area[x_, t_] := Pi (topr[x, t]^2 - botr[x, t]^2)
ap = 20/3 10^-6
bi = 80/3 10^-6

L = 2000 10^-6
lambda = 2
Ro = -.2
w = 2 Pi
bo = 40 10^-6
volann[t_] := Integrate[area[x, t], {x, 0, L}]
dvol[t_] := D[volann[t], t]
```

When I try to evaluate `volann[0.01]`, I get the correct numerical value, but when I ask for `dvol[0.01]`, I get the following message:

> General::ivar: 0.01` is not a valid variable. >>

[image: diff]

The number is the correct answer to `volann[0.01]`.  How do I ask *Mathematica* to evaluate the derivative of `volann` with respect to `t` at different values of `t`?

I am not even certain I am using the `:=` operator correctly.

Comment: Try using `=` instead of `:=` in the definitions for `volann` and `dvol`, and report back.

Answer (score 3):

As J.M. stated in his comment, in the last two function definitions you need to use [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) rather than [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) ,

I would further recommend applying 'N`, the numeric evaluator to the result of the integration.

```
 volann[t_] = N[Integrate[area[x, t], {x, 0, L}]]
```

> ```
> .5348*10^-12 - 5.58505*10^-14 Cos[3.14159 (0.004 + 4. t)] + 
>   1.77778*10^-10 (Sin[3.14159 (0.002 - 2. t)] + Sin[6.28319 t]) -  
>   4.44444*10^-13 Sin[6.28319 (0.004 + 2. t)] -  
>   1.06667*10^-10 (-1. Sin[3.14159 (0.004 + 2. t)] + 
>   Sin[3.14159 (0.006 + 2. t)]) +  
>   4.44444*10^-13 Sin[3.14159 (0.012 + 4. t)]
> ```

```
volann[.01]
```

> ```
> 5.93188*10^-12
> ```

Now evaluating

```
 dvol[t_] = D[volann[t], t]
```

will give

> ```
> 1.77778*10^-10 (-6.28319 Cos[3.14159 (0.002 - 2. t)] + 6.28319 Cos[6.28319 t]) - 
>   5.58505*10^-12 Cos[6.28319 (0.004 + 2. t)] - 
>   1.06667*10^-10 
>     (-6.28319 Cos[3.14159 (0.004 + 2. t)] + 6.28319 Cos[3.14159 (0.006 + 2. t)]) + 
>   5.58505*10^-12 Cos[3.14159 (0.012 + 4. t)] + 
>   7.01839*10^-13 Sin[3.14159 (0.004 + 4. t)]
> ```

and

```
dvol[.01]
```

> ```
> -2.55924*10^-15
> ```